# ElasticBeanstalk GoDaddy and SSL

Tags: ssl, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I am attempting to get my domain (assetfarm.com.au) to use SSL. I have created a certificate and uploaded it to IAM. I associated it with my ElasticBeanstalk configuration.

I am also attempting to use Route 53 for my domain. Here are my current settings:

[image: Route 53 Settings]

[image]

[image]

I'm using a self-signed certificate just to check that the issue wasn't with the certificate GoDaddy generated. Despite following the instructions on Amazon step-by-step, I am still unable to visit https://www.assetfarm.com.au or https://assetfarm.com.au. I can't even visit https with the elastic beanstalk or load balancer URL.

Comment: Check your ELB Security Group for Port 443

Comment: That was it! Add that comment as an answer if you like and I'll mark it correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your ELB Security Group for Port 443.
For some new AWS accounts, you may need to open Port 443 manually.